How do I rig an object to glide across the surface of another object when translated?

I'm having trouble figuring out how to rig the eye geo of the character in a way that allows me to translate the bone so that the eye geo glides across the surface of the body geo. Any help is appreciated!!

Hello what do you mean by "glides across the surface when translated", could you please show a storyboard or drawing?

Not sure how experienced you are. Here is a more advanced technique.

 Thanks for your response! A shrinkwrap bone constraint seemed to do the trick!

Lets say that this deformed sphere is a head. In front of it I have a circle (the eye), with a little bit of space left between the two. It's important to have the proper normals orientation (in blue).

Then I create the armature with a head bone that controls the head, an eye bone that controls the eye, and an eye controller bone.
The eye bone is parented to the eye controller bone, and the eye controller is parented to the head bone.

I then select the eye bone and add a Damped Track Constraint, targeting the head bone, with the following settings.
(Warning: add this constraint in the Bone constraint tab, NOT in the Object constraint tab).

Next, I select the circle (the eye) and add a Shrinkwrap modifier that follows the surface of the sphere, with the following settings.

And that's basically it! And if you want the eye to have some thickness, just add a solidify modifier to it.

I would also recommend locking the Y axis of the eye controller bone, to avoid any glitches, and only use the eye controller to move the eye.

In case I wasn't clear enough, here is the file: 

Nice challenge!!
Here's one idea, if your target surface is not too severely curved at many points.  It is not including Geo-Nodes.
I would use a eye-bone that is geo-centered on the character head where it's pose bone tail can be referenced.

I create a mesh with a single vertex.  I would then not parent the Single_Vertex object to the bone, but instead use copy location & rotation of the bone tail, and shrinkwrap the single vertex to above the Head object.

Finally, I would take the Eye object, and copy rotation and location of the Single Vertex.  Rotation is Added so that I can pre-adjust the rotation, that will then track the Vertex rotation.

You can pose the bone in the following and see that the Eye is more well behaved on the smaller "bump" and less so on the high ridge (for instance, an ear) 
